# Python version keeps saying 3.8.8 in terminal while I just downloaded Python 3.9.1

Tags: python

I recently downloaded Python 3.9.1 (for a second time, the old version was deleted) and I'm trying to add it to PATH. I'm following the steps listed here: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac, but when I execute the "python --version" command in terminal after going through the steps above, it still says "Python 3.8.8". How can I update it to say "Python 3.9.1"? I'm pretty sure I deleted the old version completely (dragged it from Applications to trash, removed the framework, and removed the symbolic links).

Comment: Try to uninstall python3.8

Comment: use `which python` and hunt down all alternate locations of python, then delete those

Answer (score 0):

This means both the python versions are installed. It is just that by default python 3.8.8 has been taken official, what you may need to do is to check with which command, then you can either change the bashrc to configure the newer version of python, in your case 3.9. Alternatively you can manage the versions.

Here is a link but useful: [How to install and manage multiple versions of python on Linux](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-on-linux-916990dabe4b)

Alternatively, this is a good article on understanding the usage of pyenv for your python installs, [right here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/).

Comment: We expect the necessary information to answer the question *in the answer itself* - please only use links to cite / attribute quotations (e.g. show where in the documentation it says what you are claiming) or give supplementary information. If this were not a duplicate question, a proper answer should show *how* to configure `bashrc`, the PATH variable or whatever else.